# PHP Function is only called once in for loop

Tags: php, function, for-loop

I am sure that this question has been asked before, but I am unable to come up with the proper keywords (especially in english).

I am using PHP and I am trying to for loop through a parameter of a function. So the function should be called, store the retrieved data in some variables and these variables should then be inserted into a database.

However, the loops only runs once! If I substitute $id with any number it works fine, but only once.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<9; $i++) {
    $id = $rows[$i][1];
    $values = getDetails($id); // This function (from another file) returns an array

    $title = $values["Title"];
    $year = $values["Year"];

    $query=  " INSERT INTO database
        VALUES ('','$title','$year')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

*** EDIT This is part of the getDetails function:

```
function getDetails($id) {

$url = "http://www.something.de/". $id . "/";
$html = file_get_html ( $url );
$title = $html->find('span[itemprop=name]');
$title = explode('>',$title[0]);
$title = explode('</span',$title[1]);

... // This might look weird and is definatly not perfect, but it works :)

$details = array("Title" => $title[0], "Year" => $year[1]);
return $details;
}
```

*** EDIT
WOW! I found the reason ... I had a function within my function which was never used. I just commented it out and my code works just fine. I assume it is not a good idea to so anyways.

Comment: Have you checked if the query is executed at all ? Moreover , try to test if the for loop terminates after the first iteration (add some prints to check it).

Comment: Do you have a table in your DB called database? If not that insert is probably failing. Try to var_dump the result and see what you get. This loop should run for i = 0 to 8

Comment: You should do a while loop on what you're loading the $rows with.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The loop (I echoed $i) runs with the second value until the function call "$values = getDetails($id);"
After that call, the second value is not been printed.

Comment: What does getDetails return? Also, your code is vunerable to SQL Injection. Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php to protect againts this.

Comment: The database exists ... it does run one time and inserts a row properly.
getDeetails returns an array. I am using another php file for this function since it is using Simple HTML Dom.

Comment: Is it possible that this code is executed to fast for my function to return something?

Comment: What values are in the array? Does the title have quotes? Does it return an array for the specific IDs you are returning after the first run of the loop?

Comment: This is a print_r of the return value of $values:
Array ( [Title] => something [Year] => 2011)
It is only printed once, the loop terminates after the function call.

Comment: Show the code for getDetails. I think that the problem is there.

Comment: I edited the original post with part of the getDetails function (it's quite a beast).

Comment: Show the part where $title is created please. What happens if the page with id $id does not exist?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I updated the function. I did not build in any catch block, I would do so when everyhting works as expected (and it works, apart from the not looping).

Comment: One shouldn't use a function within a function and always post the whole code ... I learned that the hard way :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your $query is wrong.

Change this:

```
$query=  " INSERT INTO database
        VALUES ('','$title','$year')";
```

To something like this:

```
$query=  " INSERT INTO database (field1,field2,field3)
        VALUES ('','$title','$year')";
```

Is your ID field autoincrementing? If so you do not need the "field1" entry at all.

Happy Coding!

Comment: That doesn't matter. Its still a valid query syntax

Comment: if the first field of the table is an integer that is autoincrementing and is the primary key you would not be able to insert 2 '' in the same table.

Comment: If you reference [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) it states "If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement. If you do not know the order of the columns in the table, use DESCRIBE tbl_name to find out."  The structure of the table is important.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem...I am willing to help. Just provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also.

I could print to a table without a problem the parameters I was feeding into a function in a loop. But the function calls in the loops would only call once.

SOLUTION: Remove the location redirects and the exit(); from the function.

Hope this helps someone else.